# Getting an input from the user and traverse over a list to chek if the input is present on the list

Tags: python, list, user-input

I have two lists, I want the user to enter a word and my program should check from my lists if that word is present and print something, and if the entered word is not in either of the lists it must execute the else statement.

here is my code:

```
animal = ['dog','goat','cow', 'ship']

city = ['JHB', 'CP', 'NY']

user = input('> ')

inp = user.split()

for word in inp:

    if word == animal:
        print(f"Your entry is: {word}")

    elif word == city:
        print(f"Your entry os: {word}")

    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

When I run the code it jumps to the, "else" statement.

Comment: Use `in` to test if something is in a list, not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `==`, use `in` since it's a list:

```
for word in inp:

    if word in animal:
        print(f"Your entry is: {word}")

    elif word in city:
        print(f"Your entry os: {word}")

    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```